# TB_GETBUTTONINFO fails on Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, windows-messages

I have some code like this:

```
TBBUTTONINFO mtbbi;
HWND hwnd;
HANDLE hProc;
DWORD dwProcessID;
void* lpData;
```

.....

```
GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &dwProcessID);
hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, dwProcessID);
lpData = VirtualAllocEx(hProc , 0, sizeof(TBBUTTONINFO), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
memset(&mtbbi,0,sizeof(mtbbi));
mtbbi.cbSize=sizeof(TBBUTTONINFO);
mtbbi.dwMask=TBIF_BYINDEX|TBIF_LPARAM;  
WriteProcessMemory(hProc,lpData,&mtbbi,sizeof(TBBUTTONINFO),&dwBytesRead);
SendMessage(hwnd, TB_GETBUTTONINFO, 0, (LPARAM)lpData);
ReadProcessMemory(hProc, lpData, &mtbbi, sizeof(TBBUTTONINFO), &dwBytesRead);
```

where `hwnd` - is a toolbar handle. This handle is correct, other messages(like `TB_BUTTONCOUNT` or `TB_GETBUTTON`) work fine.
So, this code is working correctly under Windows XP, but when I try to execute it under Windows 7 x64 `SendMessage` returns -1, which means an error. I tried to use `GETBUTTONINFOA` instead of `GETBUTTONINFO`, but result is the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When in Rome, act like a Roman.  If that program you are hacking is running elevated then you have to run elevated as well.  If it is 64-bit process then you have to be a 64-bit process as well.  Don't hack the taskbar, that's an ungreek thing to do.

Comment: On the face of it: wrong struct size, wrong hwnd, wrong button index. Maybe you should do a complete repro case including a message that works. I'm sure someone will debug it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it. Problem was that `TBBUTTONINFO` structure contains pointers, which take double size in 64-bit processes. I made my own structure, replacing pointers with int64, and with this structure SendMessage work as expected. Thanks to everyone for help.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Windows Vista the User Interface Privilege Isolation provides restrictions to the system that prevents lower-privilege applications from sending window messages or installing hooks in higher-privilege processes. However, higher-privilege applications are still permitted to send window messages to lower-privilege processes. These restrictions are implemented throw `SendMessage` and other message sending functions.

I'm not sure whether this is the cause for your problem, because in general, read-only message are not blocked even from lower-privilege processes. Your `TB_GETBUTTONINFO` seem to be such a message, same for `TB_BUTTONCOUNT` and `TB_GETBUTTON`. However, you should investigate this.

See [Windows Integrity Mechanism Design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625963.aspx) for more information.